# Can なになに be used to fill in an unknown word in an example? i.e. なになにともうします。

Tags: expressions, word-requests

In English you teach someone how to say their name by saying: My name is ''blah blah'' or My name is ''whatever''. Your voice drops on the words blah blah and whatever to show that your name is not actually blah blah or whatever and there is a little pause beforehand. I speak Mandarin Chinese and when saying a sentence that requires inputting a certain word you can include 什么什么 which literally means ''なになに''　or ''what what'' but in this context means ''blah blah'' or ''whatever''.

How to say your name in Japanese:

> My name is blah blah.
>   _______ ともうします。
>   なになにともうします。

How to say you like something in Japanese.

> I like blah blah.
>   _________ がすきです。
>   なになにがすきです。

On paper it can be expressed by ______ . But can this be read as なになに ?

Answer (score 4):

A placeholder for any word would be [まるまる](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%80%87%E3%80%87) expressed as 〇〇.

> 〇〇{まるまる}と申します。
>   〇〇{まるまる}が好きです。

---

Another one, especially if it was a quiz and you'd expect an exact answer (scratched out), you might go for [ぺけぺけ](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BA%E3%81%91%E3%81%BA%E3%81%91) sometimes expressed as ××.

> 日本の首都はペケペケです。